# How to identify a good location to catch Signal Crayfish near River Don

Tags: fishing, uk

Would anyone know how to identify a good location to catch Cray Fish at the [River Don](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Don,_Yorkshire)? 
I live in Doncaster (UK) and so the River Don would be ideal to catch the [American Signal Crayfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_crayfish).

Looking at the license application, I am required to enter a GPS grid reference on my fishing location. Not very practical before you find a good fishing mark.

Comment: Some 2012 information in [New insights into the status of Signal Crayfish in the Don Catchment](https://dcrt.org.uk/archives/808), but this does not merit an answer (500 m resolution). [Full paper here](https://dcrt.org.uk/archives/1026)

Comment: I would base my reference where I expect to have access to the river. Anecdotally crayfish tend to enjoy areas with largish rocky bottoms, while those fishing for them prefer streams with depths that are about waist high or less, with not too fast of a current.